# How to add special characters in html hidden value

Tags: html, html-escape-characters

I want to put the value="name+asc" in hidden field. Http method is Get.

```
<input type="hidden" value="name+asc" name="sort" />
```

But I cannot put the name+asc in URL.

How can I handle that problem.

Comment: Are you using any server side languages like php or c#?  If so you need to use the urlencode functions for that language.

Comment: Yes. I am using server side language Java and Spring MVC. Can I use to encode JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Values of form inputs will be automatically encoded correctly when a form is submitted. In `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, a `+` sign represents a space so the browser will encode it as `%2B`.

If you want to submit a form with `+` in the data: The code you have is fine.

If you want to submit a form with a space in the data: Use a literal space. The browser will encode it for you.

If you want to read form data with JavaScript and construct a URL (or post request) programatically when pass the data through the `encodeURIComponent` method.

```
var value = "123+456";
var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(value);
var url = "http://example.com/?query=" + encodedValue;
```

If you want to construct a URI by hand (e.g. for pasting into an HREF attribute) then you will need to look up the encoded values … somewhere. I tend to run node.js in a terminal so I can quickly type `encodeURIComponent('a string literal');`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the + will automatically split your values unless encoded to special characters. You can use a - or a _ instead of the +.